# check facebook session onload

Tags: javascript, facebook

Below I am trying to check the session of facebook on page load. And want to show different content on page as per login status. What's wrong?

I want first two check the user connection status. Then only appropriate content to be shown on the page.

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1781292862',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
//      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };



window.onload(){
FB.init({
    appId  : '178812862', // Your FB app ID from www.facebook.com/developers/
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {

    alert("yes");
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll want to use `response.status` instead of `response.session`. And since the status is going to be string either way ("connected", "not_authorized", or "unknown"), you'll want to set up your `if` statements accordingly. The following example is from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

Let me know if that makes sense, or if you have any questions :)

### Update

Your script is still missing the little closure that loads the facebook sdk into your document (which is why you're getting the error that FB is not defined). Try replacing your whole script block with the following:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : 1343434343, // Your FB app ID from www.facebook.com/developers/
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            alert("yes");
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

        } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        }
    });
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

(^That last part is what loads the facebook sdk.) Try it out and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: thanks, I tried this already. When I replace your code in my original and try to do alert(), no response.

Comment: Also try replacing `window.onload(){` with `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {` and make sure you've added a `};` at the end (looks like `onload()`'s currently not closed properly)

Comment: Let me know how this^ goes :)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). Did you include the FB sdk (starts with `// Load the SDK asynchronously`)?

Comment: It's still missing the part where you load the Facebook SDK. Check out my updated answer and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37584/discussion-between-user2129623-and-asifrc)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            id= response.id;
            if(id==undefined)
            {
            alert('I am logged out');                    
            }
            else
            {
            alert('I am logged in');
            }
        })
    }
});
```